# Reset laptop battery data or interface battery chip?

Tags: laptop, battery, calibration

My battery consists of 5 parallel strings of 2 cells in series. One conductor broke and therefore the measured capacity of the battery decreased dramatically, so that the capacity meter went down a lot.

I have now repaired the battery and I get the battery time I got before it broke but the battery meter still thinks that my battery has the lower capacity resulting in that i can not know how much energy is left in the battery at a specific time. I can run the computer for several hours after the battery states 0% left.

The problem is the same in both Windows XP and Ubuntu 10.04. The computer is an Asus eee 1000H. I have tried to completely drain and recharge the battery and then fully charge it to reset the battery stats but it did not work.

Is there another way for me to reset the data in the battery supervising chip or write data to it. Or as a bad solution, ignore the battery data and just numerically integrate the power over time giving the full energy and then use that instead of the data that the battery provides.

Comment: This likely would be unique to the exact battery model.  Besides that does this device have an integrated non-removable battery?  How did you repair something you can't even replace?

Comment: The battery is user removable. Also all batteries are replaceable, it's just a matter of difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

How to reset a battery is a well kept secret, I have done several unfruitful searches, but I only found irrelevant information on programs that show the battery charge capacity and actual charge, or how to discharge the battery for a longer life, but never how to reset the chip in the battery.

My original battery cells show a good charge level, when tested with a multimeter, but, the chip ensures that the battery will never be usable again.

I found a [guide (PDF)](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Miller/BH_US_11_Miller_Battery_Firmware_Public_WP.pdf) that teaches how the battery control system works in some apple models.
I am not a hardware expert, but it seems a good document for those with knowledge in electronics.